# The order of wxPython events is causing me problems

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

My GUI consists of a `wx.ListCtrl` on the left, with a list of objects to edit, and a set of `wx.TextCtrl`s on the right, for editing the selected object.

My strategy for implementing this was:

- On a textbox's `wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS` , update the relevant attribute of the currently selected object
- On the list's `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_DESELECTED`, either hide the textboxes or blank them out and disable them (needed for when the user clicks the blank space in the list control)
- On the list's `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED`, populate the text controls with the values of the selected object's attributes

With this setup, there are 3 use cases, and 2 of them work:

1. When the user is clicking/tabbing between textboxes, the correct `wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS`s occur, and the attributes get updated.
2. When the user clicks from a textbox into the blank space in the list, that's OK as well: first `wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS` causes the attribute to update, and then `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_DESELECTED` hides the textboxes.
3. The problem is when the user clicks directly from a textbox to another object in the list control. The order of events in this case is `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_DESELECTED`, `wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED`, and then finally `wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS`. You can probably see the problem: by the time the method that updates attributes is called, a new object has already been selected and the textboxes have been populated with new values.

So I know exactly what the problem is, but I can't come up with a nice, clean way to fix it. Ideally I'd like to be able to change the order of the wx events (putting `wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS` at the front), but I doubt that's possible. Is there some other obvious solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_DESELECTED will only fire when the user changes the selected object in the list box.  This serves the same purpose as losing focus on the text box.  Call the update routines from that event as well.  To skip the subsequent wx.EVT_KILL_FOCUS from the text box set a "isDirty" attribute in the parent object after you update the attributes.  You can check the isDirty value anytime to confirm there are changes to commit.  This attribute would have to be reset when you populate the text boxes for the new selection and then set during other textbox events.

Comment: Good idea, I think this will work well. I'm working on something else at the moment, but I'll give this a try when I come back to this problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are trying to re-implement from scratch the functionality of wxListbook.  It seems like a lot of work, perhaps you can use wxListbook
 to do what you need.

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.9.4/classwx_listbook.html

Comment: Hmm, this is a good point also. Something else to think about when I come back to this problem.

Comment: It turns out wxListBook is no good for me, because "The underlying wxListCtrl displays page labels in a one-column report view". I need multiple columns.